# How to deploy ETL package to a remote SQL Server with SQL authentication?

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl

I'm new to ETL so I have developed a simple ETL package, and now I'm going to deploy it to a remote server.

I connect to server using SQL Server authentication, so I go to solution explorer and open deployment wizard, in there in destination tab entered my server ip and then it shows me a error message saying

> Login failed for user 'MYDOMAIN\MYUSERNAME'. (.Net SqlClient Data Provider)

As I said earlier I want to use SQL Server authentication to connect to my server, where can I change this settings in SSIS ?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the link below. I think it should solve your problem.

> On the Specify Target SQL Server page, specify the instance of SQL Server to install the packages to and select an authentication mode. If you select SQL Server Authentication, you must provide a user name and a password.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141693(v=sql.110).aspx